# How to process groups of rows based on 3 different conditions in pandas hopefully in a vectorized way?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, vectorization

Considering a Dataframe with two columns: `timestamps` (sorted) and `temperature` (not necessarily sorted) and a list of timestamps (list of start and end) that defines windows,
I would like to process each of these windows as a group.

Within each of these groups, I would like to retrieve the timestamp corresponding to the 1st `temp` value being equal or larger than `temp_limit`.

And I would like to do it the fastest way possible of course :)

An example will likely provide a better explanation, I have implemented this using `iterrows`. Please, is there any vectorized way to managed this? (or maybe with `groupby()` that I think, even if not vectorized, would be faster than `iterrows`)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Define input data: Dataframe with 'ts' and 'temp' columns.
ts = pd.date_range(start='2020/01/01 08:00', end='2020/01/02 08:00', freq='2H')
temp = np.arange(len(ts)) + 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ts, 'temp':temp})

# 'windows' DataFrame gathers the list of timestamps in column 'ts',
# and list of temperature thresholds in 'temp_lim'.
ts_win = ts[::4]
temp_lim = temp[::4]+2
windows = pd.DataFrame({'ts_win': ts_win, 'temp_lim': temp_lim})[:-1]


# Doing now the processing in a non vectorized way
# Results are stored in column 'ts' of DataFrame 'res'
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ts'], index=range(len(windows)))
windows['later_ts_win'] = windows['ts_win'].shift(-1, fill_value=df['ts'].iloc[-1])
i=0
for row in windows.iterrows():
    _, row = row
    ts1, ts2 = row['ts_win'], row['later_ts_win']
    m_df = (df['ts'] > ts1) & (df['ts'] <= ts2) & (df['temp'] >= row['temp_lim'])
    res['ts'].iloc[i] = df.loc[m_df,'ts'].iloc[0]     
    i+=1
```

Input DataFrames are then:

```py
df

                    ts  temp
0  2020-01-01 08:00:00    10
1  2020-01-01 10:00:00    11
2  2020-01-01 12:00:00    12
3  2020-01-01 14:00:00    13
4  2020-01-01 16:00:00    14
5  2020-01-01 18:00:00    15
6  2020-01-01 20:00:00    16
7  2020-01-01 22:00:00    17
8  2020-01-02 00:00:00    18
9  2020-01-02 02:00:00    19
10 2020-01-02 04:00:00    20
11 2020-01-02 06:00:00    21
12 2020-01-02 08:00:00    22

windows
               ts_win  temp_lim
0 2020-01-01 08:00:00        12
1 2020-01-01 16:00:00        16
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00        20
```

Result is then

```py
res
                    ts
0  2020-01-01 12:00:00
1  2020-01-01 20:00:00
2  2020-01-02 04:00:00
```

So, reviewing the 1st iteration of the loop:

- the group of rows with ts > '2020-01-01 08:00:00' and <= '2020-01-01 16:00:00' is processed
- within this group, the 1st ts for which temp is larger or equal than '12' (`temp_lim`) is retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) without exact matches. Then filter the dataset for temps greater or equal to the limit, aggregate on `ts_win` and take the first row. You can then take the columns you need.

```
d = pd.merge_asof(df, windows, left_on='ts', right_on='ts_win', allow_exact_matches=False)

print(d.loc[d.temp >= d.temp_lim].groupby('ts_win').first())

                                     ts  temp  temp_lim
ts_win                                                 
2020-01-01 08:00:00 2020-01-01 12:00:00    12      12.0
2020-01-01 16:00:00 2020-01-01 20:00:00    16      16.0
2020-01-02 00:00:00 2020-01-02 04:00:00    20      20.0
```

Note: `merge_asof` expects both datasets to be sorted by the key.

Comment: Thanks, look promising. I am investigating this approach! (studying different options and their execution time)